# Как контролировать выполнение функции посредством уменьшения / увеличения экрана? JS

Tags: javascript, match-media

У меня есть этично украденная (кхм, скопированная) функция, которая реализует поведение сайдбара так же, как и сайдбар ВК.

Но при уменьшении экрана, когда применяется медиа-запрос, при прокрутке среднего блока, к которому "привязан" сайдбар, ломается верстка сайдбара, а точнее текст выстраивается по левому краю в столбик по-одному слову и блок перестает прокручиваться.

Я пробовал добавлять доп.классы к сайдбару и меню и при уменьшении страницы убирать их, но тогда, после обратного увеличения размеров страницы, функция отказывается работать.

Вопрос: как реализовать отключения данной функции при размерах экрана

```
<= 768px
```

и включение при экране

```
> 768px
```

Я читал много разных ответов и примеров по типу: менять значение `x` с `true` на `false` и отслеживать значение `x` в функции и активировать, отключать ее в зависимости от значения переменной, **но** у меня не получилось этого сделать.

Пожалуйста, покажите мне на наглядном примере, как это реализовать.

Вот код функции:

```
(function () {
  var a = document.querySelector(".l-menu"),
    b = null,
    K = null,
    Z = 0,
    P = 20,
    N = 0; // если у P ноль заменить на число, то блок будет прилипать до того, как верхний край окна браузера дойдёт до верхнего края элемента, если у N — нижний край дойдёт до нижнего края элемента. Может быть отрицательным числом
  window.addEventListener("scroll", Ascroll, false);
  document.body.addEventListener("scroll", Ascroll, false);
  function Ascroll() {
    var Ra = a.getBoundingClientRect(),
      R1bottom = document.querySelector(".m-menu").getBoundingClientRect()
        .bottom;
    if (Ra.bottom < R1bottom) {
      if (b == null) {
        var Sa = getComputedStyle(a, ""),
          s = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < Sa.length; i++) {
          if (
            Sa[i].indexOf("overflow") == 0 ||
            Sa[i].indexOf("padding") == 0 ||
            Sa[i].indexOf("border") == 0 ||
            Sa[i].indexOf("outline") == 0 ||
            Sa[i].indexOf("box-shadow") == 0 ||
            Sa[i].indexOf("background") == 0
          ) {
            s += Sa[i] + ": " + Sa.getPropertyValue(Sa[i]) + "; ";
          }
        }
        b = document.createElement("div");
        b.className = "stop";
        b.style.cssText =
          s + " box-sizing: border-box; width: " + a.offsetWidth + "px;";
        a.insertBefore(b, a.firstChild);
        var l = a.childNodes.length;
        for (var i = 1; i < l; i++) {
          b.appendChild(a.childNodes[1]);
        }
        a.style.height = b.getBoundingClientRect().height + "px";
        a.style.padding = "0";
        a.style.border = "0";
      }
      var Rb = b.getBoundingClientRect(),
        Rh = Ra.top + Rb.height,
        W = document.documentElement.clientHeight,
        R1 = Math.round(Rh - R1bottom),
        R2 = Math.round(Rh - W);
      if (Rb.height > W) {
        if (Ra.top < K) {
          // скролл вниз
          if (R2 + N > R1) {
            // не дойти до низа
            if (Rb.bottom - W + N <= 0) {
              // подцепиться
              b.className = "sticky";
              b.style.top = W - Rb.height - N + "px";
              Z = N + Ra.top + Rb.height - W;
            } else {
              b.className = "stop";
              b.style.top = -Z + "px";
            }
          } else {
            b.className = "stop";
            b.style.top = -R1 + "px";
            Z = R1;
          }
        } else {
          // скролл вверх
          if (Ra.top - P < 0) {
            // не дойти до верха
            if (Rb.top - P >= 0) {
              // подцепиться
              b.className = "sticky";
              b.style.top = P + "px";
              Z = Ra.top - P;
            } else {
              b.className = "stop";
              b.style.top = -Z + "px";
            }
          } else {
            b.className = "";
            b.style.top = "";
            Z = 0;
          }
        }
        K = Ra.top;
      } else {
        if (Ra.top - P <= 0) {
          if (Ra.top - P <= R1) {
            b.className = "stop";
            b.style.top = -R1 + "px";
          } else {
            b.className = "sticky";
            b.style.top = P + "px";
          }
        } else {
          b.className = "";
          b.style.top = "";
        }
      }
      window.addEventListener(
        "resize",
        function () {
          a.children[0].style.width = getComputedStyle(a, "").width;
        },
        false
      );
    }
  }
})();
```

P.S. в коде ничего не менял еще, даже комментарии не трогал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.innerWidth` - Дает текущую ширину окна в пикселях.

```js
console.log( typeof window.innerWidth)
console.log( window.innerWidth );
```

Решение будет таким:

```
function Ascroll() {
  if (window.innerWidth < 768) return; 

  // Остальное - не трогать
```

При этом, функция всё равно будет запускаться при любом скролле, но прерываться (`return`), если ширина оказалась меньше 768 (проверьте, вам нужно именно строго меньше 768 или меньше либо равно `<= 768`?)

---

Существует и такой подход (не трогая функцию Ascroll):

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
  if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", Ascroll);
  } else {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", Ascroll); // Третий параметр и так по умолчанию false
  }
});
```

Формально, так происходит меньше "затрат" на проверку `window.innerWidth < 768`, но это не серьезно, т.к. речь идет всего о нескольких вызовах в секунду. Первый вариант просто удобнее.

Comment: Здравствуйте, огромное спасибо за ответ. К сожалению, я уже выключил компьютер. Завтра, как включу - проверю.

Comment: И, если можно, одно уточнение. Моя функция должна располагаться в первом примере в else? Т.е. ```function Ascroll() { if(...) return; else { моя функция}}``` Иизвиняюсь за то, что все в одну строку, на телефоне отправляет при переносе строки.

Comment: @ZiEnTenIn Нет, прямо в функции, в самом начале добавить строчку `if (...) return; ` else не нужен.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Кроме предложенного метода c `innerWidth` можно так же воспользоваться методом интерфейса [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window), под названием [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia), который вернет boolean значение в зависимости от собственных настроек и размера viewport'a клиента:

```js
console.log(window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)").matches)
```

```
function Ascroll() {
  if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)").matches) return 
}
```